# How can i create Multi-page applications in PyQt4?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt4

I had a little research regarding this question, but i couldn't find any simple answer or tutorial to do this.

---

I'm trying to find a widget, that will make transition between pages using QPushButton. I have heard of QStackWidget, But i'm not exactly sure how to use it, I have found many tutorials, but all of them were hard to understand.

---

So for example, i have a window class:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class Window(QtGui.QMainWindow):
```

How can i add QStackWidget to this class? (Without any layouts)

If i do so, how can i switch to specific page using QPushButton? (With adding multiple widgets in one index)

**extra**: is it possible to add some kind of effect on transition? like fading, etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class Window(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        self.stacked_widget = QtGui.QStackedWidget()
        self.button = QtGui.QPushButton("Next")

        self.button.clicked.connect(self.__next_page)

        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.stacked_widget)
        layout.addWidget(self.button)

        widget = QtGui.QWidget()
        widget.setLayout(layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(widget)

        self.stacked_widget.addWidget(QtGui.QLabel("Page 1"))
        self.stacked_widget.addWidget(QtGui.QLabel("Page 2"))
        self.stacked_widget.addWidget(QtGui.QLabel("Page 3"))

    def __next_page(self):
        idx = self.stacked_widget.currentIndex()
        if idx < self.stacked_widget.count() - 1:
            self.stacked_widget.setCurrentIndex(idx + 1)
        else:
            self.stacked_widget.setCurrentIndex(0)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Window()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: sorry for being annoying, but how do i add multiple widgets on index? @gyu-don

Comment: Sorry, but i didn't understand code quite well, I want to add multipe widgets on single index @gyu-don

Comment: QStackedWidget have only 1 index. If you want to show multiple widgets, you can use layout. Here is an example; https://gist.github.com/gyu-don/cc6358fddb04df7067a68279ddd433a2

Comment: and hopefully this is last question, Is it possible to do it without using layouts? to move widget everywhere, @gyu-don

Comment: QStackedWidget is not for making movable widget. You may want QDockWidget. It is movable. https://gist.github.com/gyu-don/d93e77e939e7b8255572ee2bdc69f87e Otherwise, you may want QDialog.

Comment: i mean moving it from code, like this (`self.setGeometry(100, 100`). @gyu-don

Comment: Fixed it: http://pastebin.com/5wEmkJKe, i just wanted it to be without layout, thanks for helping me!